# The challenge room is locked but I have full health

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

This question here:

[How do you open the barred doors in the Binding of Isaac?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31324/how-do-you-open-the-barred-doors-in-the-binding-of-isaac)

says I should be able to open these challenge doors with full health. But I've had multiple instances where the room is locked even when I have completely full health. In fact, check this out, I started the level with full health, plus some, and I can't even get anymore! Look:

[image]

The challenge room is right there, I have full health, and this is how I started the level. What's the deal?

Comment: Not sure if it matters but the linked duplicate is for an older version of the game. When I searched for an answer, it didn't come up. Is there a way to tag it with Rebirth as well since it's relevant. So people who search for Rebirth can find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a boss challenge room. Indicated by the skull on top of the swords.

To enter these you need to have maximum one full red heart. It does not matter how many blue/black hearts you have. You can also have as many empty red heart containers as you want.

Other options to get in are using items/consumables that open all doors (such as dads key) or bombing your way in if there is a secret room adjacent.

Comment: Oh wow, I never even noticed the difference! Thank you!